# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que ng-repeat no me repita la misma variable varias veces por medio de $scope.apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Puedo imprimir todos los datos de mi html en `ng-repeat`, utilizando la función `$scope.apply();`

Ahora el inconveniente es que me está mostrando una misma variable varias veces de la siguiente manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy implementando es el siguiente:

```
mi_html = $compile(angular.element('#cuerpocorreo'))($scope);

$timeout(function(){
     $scope.$apply();
     print_win = new BrowserWindow();
     print_win.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(mi_html[0].innerHTML)); 
     print_win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
         print_win.webContents.print(); 
     });
     print_win.on('closed', function() {
          print_win = null;
     });

 })
```

Y para generar los `ng-repeat` el código es:

```
<tr ng-repeat="elemento in arreglo_seleccion">
     <td>{{elemento['@IUnAlterno']}}</td>
     <td style="text-align:right;">{{parseFloat(elemento['@valor'])|currency}}</td>
     <td>{{elemento['@areaPrivada']}}</td>
     <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaConstruida']}}</td>
     <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaLote']}}</td>
     <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaTecnica']}}</td>
     <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaTerraza']}}</td>
     <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaBalcon']}}</td>
     <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaPatio']}}</td>
     <td ng-if="!es_habitacional(elemento)" colspan="6">DESCRIPCION</td>
 </tr>
```

Y me genera esto:

¿Qué es lo que falla y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de los datos que tendrías en `arreglo_seleccion`? ¿por que tienes datos duplicados? Quizás aplicar el filtro `unique` para que quite los duplicados no sea la mejor solución

Answer (score 1):

Para que no se muestren elementos repetidos en el **ng-repeat** podrias agregar **track by** y pones un campo que sea único en tu list

```
<tr ng-repeat="elemento in arreglo_seleccion track by elemento['@IUnAlterno']">
 <td>{{elemento['@IUnAlterno']}}</td>
 <td style="text-align:right;">{{parseFloat(elemento['@valor'])|currency}}</td>
 <td>{{elemento['@areaPrivada']}}</td>
 <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaConstruida']}}</td>
 <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaLote']}}</td>
 <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaTecnica']}}</td>
 <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaTerraza']}}</td>
 <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaBalcon']}}</td>
 <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaPatio']}}</td>
 <td ng-if="!es_habitacional(elemento)" colspan="6">DESCRIPCION</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias aplicarle un filtro de `unique` al repeat para que no se muestren repetidos

[How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que `arreglo_seleccion` almacene los datos únicos, empieza por verificar si la consulta que llena tu lista viene con los datos únicos, con el fin de descartar que debes afinar la consulta y no es problema de angular. Si la consulta trae la lista con datos únicos, ¿que variable es la que se repite? Eso no queda claro en tu pregunta. En cualquier caso tu `ng-repeat` siempre debe estar en un elemento superior al que se va a repetir, veo que lo pones en un `tr`, pero supongo que quieres que la fila se repita por cada elemento, por lo que el `ng-repeat` debería estar en el `tbody`.